# Calling a method by a String

Tags: java

I want to call a method by using a string. I get that this is possible; from what I understand reflection is the way to go. However, I'm having a hard time getting it to work and this is what I want.

For instance:

```
String method ="punch";

int punch(){
    return 1;
}
```

I want to call the method by the string name. Can someone show me an example?

```
public class foo {
    String method ="punch";

    int punch() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("foo");
        Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("punch");
        Object retObject = myMethod.invoke(null);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do so that I can get the number 1?

Comment: [Complete example found after 1 minute of googling.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Comment: Have you stepped through your code using a debugger to see what type of `Object` is returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Object retObject = myMethod.invoke(null);
```

That would only work for a static method.

For an instance method, you need to pass in the instance that you want to invoke the method on.

```
Object retObject = myMethod.invoke(instanceOfFoo);
```

Also, the method may need to be `public` (or be made accessible separately).

Comment: so something like mymethod.invoke(foo()); ? or am i way off?